# Fill cells based on values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe...

```
Key ID  Type    Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4  Sex     Race
1   A1  Type 1     x       x       x      x     Male    White
2   A1  Type 2     x       x       x      x     
3   A2  Type 1                                  Male    Black
4   A2  Type 2                      
5   A3  Type 1     x       x       x      x     Female  White
6   A3  Type 2     x       x       x      x     
7   A3  Type 3     x       x       x      x     
8   A3  Type 4     x       x       x      x
```

How can I populate the `Sex` and `Race` for all rows based on the `ID`?

```
Key ID  Type    Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4  Sex     Race
1   A1  Type 1     x       x       x      x     Male    White
2   A1  Type 2     x       x       x      x     Male    White
3   A2  Type 1                                  Male    Black
4   A2  Type 2                                  Male    Black
5   A3  Type 1     x       x       x      x     Female  White
6   A3  Type 2     x       x       x      x     Female  White
7   A3  Type 3     x       x       x      x     Female  White
8   A3  Type 4     x       x       x      x     Female  White
```

I know I can use something like `df.loc[df['ID'] == A1, 'Sex'].iloc[0]` to get the `Sex` for a particular `ID`, but not sure how I can have all blanks for `Sex` populated based on the `Sex` for each `ID`.

Comment: `df['Sex']=df['Sex'].ffill()`

Comment: @anky_91, does that logic require the rows to be in any particular order?

Comment: it takes the first valid value and fills down till the next valid value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the data by id and ffill/bfill

```
df1.replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
df1['Sex'] = df1.groupby('ID').Sex.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: Vaishali, when I run your code it doesn't make any changes to the original dataframe. When I try to assign the `groupby` code to a new dataframe, it only returns the `Sex` column, although all the values did forward filled correctly.

Comment: You need to assign the values back,  df1['Sex'] = df1.groupby('ID').Sex.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

Comment: Ah, durp! Thanks! Works great